# Homotopy classes of maps inside a Grothendieck topos

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, topos-theory, etale-cohomology

Moerdijk, *Classifying spaces and classifying topoi*, defines the Verdier cohomology of a Grothendieck topos $\mathcal E$ by taking a limit on $HC$, the homotopy of hypercoverings in $\mathcal E$.

I have some confusion on what this homotopy category is: a hyper covering is defined as a simplicial object $X_\bullet$ in $\mathcal E$ such that $X_\bullet\to 1$ is a local trivial fibration. So what does it mean that two arrows bewteen two such hyper coverings are homotopic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may be the notion of homotopy of simplicial objects inherent to any category. This is described in the stacks project's chapter on simplicial techniques.